# Perl - Parsing specific data from a file

Tags: regex, wordpress, perl, parsing

I'm trying to parse the values for DB_HOST, DB_NAME, DB_USER, and DB_PASSWORD from this block of code which is in a PHP file:

```
define('DB_NAME', 'foobar_db');
define('DB_USER', 'foobar_user');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'foobar_password');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
```

My current approach (as far as I've gotten with this anyways) is to store the file in a variable and parse the values for each define in one go using a regular expression. I can do that all fine and dandy. However, I only know basic regular expression syntax and don't know how to construct one that works for this.

I appreciate the help in advance~

Comment: What result do you want exactly? Can you rely on there never being double quotes in the code?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include that but yes, there could be double quotes.

Comment: Okay, but what result do you want exactly? How do you want the information stored?

Comment: The values in the second set of single quotes for each define. Something like my($host, $name, $user, $pass) =~ /regex/ would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should help you towards a solution. It simply extracts all the sequences of *word* characters (alphanumeric and underscore) from each line, and uses the second and third fields as the variable name and value.

This won't work if the values are ever more complex than a simple quoted string, or if the values can contain something other than word characters, such as whitespace.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
  my @fields = /\w+/g;
  my ($var, $val) = @fields[1,2];
  printf "%-12s = %s\n", $var, $val;
}

__DATA__
define('DB_NAME', 'foobar_db');
define('DB_USER', 'foobar_user');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'foobar_password');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
```

**output**

```
DB_NAME      = foobar_db
DB_USER      = foobar_user
DB_PASSWORD  = foobar_password
DB_HOST      = localhost
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll try to build on top of this and see if I can come up with a solution.